# How to effectively process a rest request in node/express js where request body contains an array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, scalability

I have a request body like following -

```
[
        {
         id:"1234",
         name:"Jayesj",
         amount:100
        },
     {
         id:"123",
         name:"Yogesh",
         amount:2090
        },
     {
         id:"12345",
         name:"Ram",
         amount:100
        },
     {
         id:"6674",
         name:"Shyam",
         amount:5000
        },
    ]
```

And I am processing each object with the help of loop -

For each object I have to do the following processing -

1. validate if all parameters in object has valid format.
2. Check if given id is present in db or not.
3. if present send request to payment gateway
4. after getting response from payment gateway I have to make an response object to put in reponse array for respective request object.

Example of response array -

```
[
    {
             id:"1234",
             pg_resp:{
                      msg:"success"
                 }
            },
         {
             id:"123",
              pg_resp:{
                      msg:"error"
                 }
            },
         {
             id:"12345",
             pg_resp:{
                      msg:"success"
                 }
            },
         {
             id:"6674",
            pg_resp:{
                      msg:"error"
                 }
            },
]
```

I have find two ways to process this request that are -

first method -

i. loop on each object
ii. after getting the complete response from payment gateway for first object
iii. make response object for first object
iv. then do this for all objects
v. then send the reponse.

in this method the request with 10 objects take 47 seconds to get response from my server

second method -

```
   i. loop on each object
   ii. send request for first object to payment gateway
  iii. dont wait for payment gateway response but return a promise
   iv. do it for all objects.
  v. promise.all all promises and make response array from that resolved promises
```

in this method the request with 10 objects take 7 seconds to get response from my server

Second method is looking more efficient but loop in it also block the event loop when objects in array are more.

I want to ask what is the most scalable way of doing such tasks in nodejs , (using a queue or what ) PLease suggest it is very imp for my business product.

Thanks to all in advanced.

Comment: Depends on how large the array can be. But no, you should not worry about blocking the event loop, you should worry running into a rate limit at your payment gateway.

Comment: @Bergi I am worrying about blocking the event loop because I have other very used endpoints in api as well , they should not be blocked because array size can be upto 5000.

Comment: and I want request to get respond to the client within 10 seconds , is some architectural pattern which can help us achieving that.

Comment: we can send some temporary response to client and give the paymnet gateway reponse at later time when we get it.

Comment: Have you tested how long it takes to iterate an array of 5000 elements? It's not a problem.

Comment: The proper solution would be to use a payment gateway that accepts batch requests.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks I test array iteration for 5000 elements , its is less than a milli second , It all depends on third party then.

Comment: @Bergi Can you suggest some proper tech for doing below thing

```we can send some temporary response to client and give the paymnet gateway reponse at later time when we get it. ```